# What happens when removing an object used by a ngRepeat in AngularJS?

Tags: iframe, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

**EDIT: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJTFe/1/) example here.**

I have a `ngRepeat` that spawns directives containing `iframes`.

```
div(ng-repeat='element in elements')
    ng-switch(on="element.type") 
        a-directive(ng-switch-when="something")
        another-directive(ng-switch-when="somethingElse")
```

Now, inside the directive I am loading content into the iframe after some event, by doing:

```
$iframe[0].contentWindow.d_contents = "html"
$iframe[0].src = 'javascript:window["d_contents"]'
```

Everything works nicely.

When I remove one of these elements from the model (in the controller) with something like:

```
elements.remove(object) //using sugarjs, that's not the issue, same behaviour with splice
```

the UI gets updated accordingly, i.e. the element disappear.

**The problem**

This works as expected:

```
elements.push(ele1)
elements.push(ele2)

.. init iframes inside ele1 and ele2 with content ..

elements.remove(ele2)
```

Result: `ele2` disappears from UI, `ele1` still there with iframe loaded

This does not:

```
elements.push(ele1)
elements.push(ele2)

.. init iframes inside ele1 and ele2 with content ..

elements.remove(ele1)
```

Result: `ele1` disappears from UI, `ele2` still there with iframe, but iframe content is back to empty, and `iframe.load()` gets fired.

What is happening here? Why is my iframe getting reseted?

Comment: Useful info : When you have 3 elements and you delete the second one, only the third iframe is reloaded.

Comment: Yes, it seems removing an element moves the other elements back 1 position and something changes in the directive..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the loading logic inside the load() to reload the content when the DOM changes.

```
var linkfn = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    init(function () {
        var $iframe = element.find("iframe")

        var refresh = function () {
            var doc = $iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
            doc.open();
            doc.write(scope.ele.source);
            doc.close();
        }

        $iframe.load(function () {
            console.log(scope.ele.id + ": loaded ");

            //refreshing
            refresh();
        });

        //initial loading
        refresh()
    })
}
```

You need to use `doc.write()` for this scenario or you will get recursive loop error.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qKgr5/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks, but that is not a solution, it is just an hack (which I did.. to avoid loop just check the body contents) - the problem is that it should not reload the contents when I remove another element.

Comment: @fusio Why is it not a solution? Why is it an hack? Why it should not reload the contents when remove the element? Do you really understand how angular works? AnguarJS binds the `entire` data from the data source whenever you add or remove from the data source.

Comment: Oh, hell. And by data source you mean the scope? Each time I modify something it reloads the entire scope? Or the data source is the array? Did not know that.

Comment: could you clarify please? I don't get why removing one array items refreshes all the following (but not the previous ones in the array) - without any notice :|